# Convert 3 redirect rules into one

Tags: nginx

A proxy app proxies to other apps with some regex in the location blocks of the `nginx.conf`. For example to a signup app called `proxy-signup-app`.

This works, but it has 3 location blocks:

```
location ~* ^/signup/(.*)/$ {
  proxy_pass https://proxy-signup-app.herokuapp.com/?proxy_regex=$1;
}
location ~* ^/signup/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass https://proxy-signup-app.herokuapp.com/?proxy_regex=$1;
}
location ~* ^/signup$ {
  proxy_pass https://proxy-signup-app.herokuapp.com/?proxy_regex=$1;
}
```

It should proxy

1. `/signup`
2. `/signup/`
3. `/signup/rainyday`
4. `/signup/rainyday/`

Where the proxy app would receive on `proxy_regex`:

1. $1 = ''
2. $1 = ''
3. $1 = 'rainyday'
4. $1 = 'rainyday' (not `/rainyday/`, `rainyday/` or `/rainyday`)

It should not redirect

- `/signups`

How to merge these location blocks into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if it's the best way, but it should work

```
location ~* ^/signup(/(.*?)/?|)$ {
  proxy_pass https://proxy-signup-app.herokuapp.com/?proxy_regex=$2;
}
```